# Floating Honeycomb window

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

How can I create a floating window in Android Honeycomb like the one of Calculator or notepad application?

I've tested with

> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"

and I get a centered transparent activity but the problem is that it isn't movable and hasn't close button.

[image: Example of floating window]

Comment: Would you consider making a widget instead?

Comment: No if it's posible in another way. Calculator application doesn't seems to be a widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That calculator you show isn't a part of Android.  Also, Android windows don't have close buttons like that.  I don't know what you are looking at, but it isn't standard Android in any way shape or form.

Comment: Whoever made your device did it.  If that is Samsung, it is Samsung.  It isn't necessarily an API, just some custom built-in stuff they did.

Answer (score 1):

AirCalc can do it https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myboyfriendisageek.aircalc&hl=en

--Edit

Just to add to my previous answer.  It doesn't need to be Custom API provided by device manufacturer as @hackbod mentioned in the above answer.

You can actually write a Service and Add a Layout to the WindowManager and set it to be TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY and there you go, your application is running on top of other applications.